# How to migrate call logs of 2 phones into a dual sim phone

Tags: backup, restore, call-history, samsung-smart-switch

I have a galaxy note 3 and galaxy note 5, both are single sim devices. I'm now switching to galaxy note 10 plus, a dual sim device. I used smart switch to migrate all data from the old phones, however the messages and call logs always restore to sim 1 in the new phone. That is, the call logs and messages made from sim 2 is restored as sim 1 in the new phone. Is there any way to properly restore the call logs and messages of 2 separate devices onto the new dual sim device

Comment: Call logs are common to the *Device* and not segregated SIM wise. Backup and restore follows the same principles. I am yet to see SIM wise backup and restore

Comment: Is it possible to manipulate the calllog.db to achieve this ? @beeshyams

Comment: I am not aware sorry